# Create Object from non-existing Type. Understanding ChangeType/Activator

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to pass an object and it's Type parameter to an application that does not have the Type and create an instance of it?

For instance

```
Application A
```

Has `Type Foo`

We instantiate it and send the value as `Object` and the `Type` to Application B

```
Application B
```

Has no References to the type `Foo`

So is it possible to say `System.Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)` and be able to convert the object or CreateInstance to be able to make a new instance of the type?

If that is confusing then lets say, I am unsure if the ChangeType uses the Type Information to convert the type or if it does a DLL lookup for short.

Comment: No, it's not, unless both applications have a reference to a shared interface. Otherwise, I think at most you could try and get the properties with reflection. Another question might come, how would you write ChangeType if you cannot refer to the type directly

Comment: This has all the hallmarks of an X-Y Problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: How is one application "sending" the object to the other?  And what is the other application going to even do with it?

Comment: How are you doing this "passing" between applications?  Are you using named pipes or some other form of IPC?

Comment: @spender I have a shared API and was wondering if I could cast the anonymous objects on the API or if I can only do it at the other client that has the reference. Mind you I am planning to do it on the referenced client, however I do not know if doing it on the API is possible so it is good to learn these things.

Comment: Why not just send the data in an easily parse-able format? JSON springs to mind.

Comment: @spender I could but I know I can do that. This is more of me trying to understand how the ChangeType or Activator works. As I know you supply a type, but I do not know if the type has to exist though according to Icepickle it does. MSDN is not very thorough on the inner workings

Comment: Theoretically you can load the assembly before casting it to a certain type, and then load the type based on a fully qualified name with assembly reference, eg: [Type.GetType(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) However, that would really overcomplicate things

Comment: @Icepickle okay so in short a DLL reference to the type is always needed and the ChangeType and Activator only use the Type information for Type Name, DLL, or Namespace lookup? I hope I'm understanding that correctly

Comment: @Icepickle Just wanted to mention based on your first comment that ChangeType takes a Type variable which I pass to the API. So it will never be referenced directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET uses type metadata from .DLL to do something with types, including object creation. So, no, .NET can't create the instance without this metadata.

Also you can't *send* any complex data between applications. You can only serialize the data to binary/XML/JSON/something-else format and then deserialize it.

.NET applications can serialize and deserialize standard .NET types, f.e. integers, floats, strings, dates and times, time spans, IP addressed, exceptions and so on.

If you want to support your own type, you should share it between applications. First, you can implement it in source code and plug your project to both solutions. Second, you can share DLL. At least you can pack your assembly to NuGet packet and install this packet to both solutions.

Of course you should make your type serializable.

Comment: Thank you, so passing the Type variable with the classes type information will not work due to the Type information missing from the local application.

Comment: In fact you can't pass Type variable between applications. Actually you can pass full type name like `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`. As you can see this name includes name of assembly, i.e. name of DLL containing the type.